# Using the Aforge genetic algorithm library to implement a chromosome which has doubles as genes?

Tags: c#, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, aforge

I downloaded the Aforge Genetics library and it's dependencies, and I have read the example provided for the IChromosome interface but I'm just not getting it, for my problem the genes of the chromosome must be doubles let's say between -1 and 1 how  can I implement that in aForge ?

If anybody has any example please share.

I admit all my previous genetic algorithm experience is with [JGAP](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/) in the Java world, so I might be asking for a feature too specific to that library and for which aForge wasn't designed if so I would appreciate if a library closer in design to JGAP but in .Net were brought to my attention.

Comment: George, could you please share a few more links, in particular to the `IChromosome` example you are referring to. In the *AForge.Genetic*  library, there is a [DoubleArrayChromosome](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/c06aaf2a-9ce3-f70b-9293-fb0fba3ef966.htm) class implementing the `IChromosome` interface, could this class solve your problems?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I've looked at the DoubleArrayChromosome and it's what I'm looking for. Could you please write and answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is the `DoubleArrayChromosome` class, which implements the `IChromosome` interface and is available in the *AForge.Genetic* library. API documentation for `DoubleArrayChromosome` is available [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/c06aaf2a-9ce3-f70b-9293-fb0fba3ef966.htm).